# Вычисление доверительных интервалов Python

Tags: python, matlab

В MATLAB есть такие методы для вычисления 95%-ых доверительных интервалов

```
ci = bootci(1000, {@corr,lsat,gpa},'alpha',0.05,'type','normal')
ci = bootci(1000, {@corr,lsat,gpa},'alpha',0.05,'type','per')
ci = bootci(1000, {@corr,lsat,gpa},'alpha',0.05,'type','cper')
```

метод  'per' (метод процентилей) знаю как сделать через python

```
 np.percentile(stat, [100 * alpha / 2., 100 * (1 - alpha / 2.)])
```

есть ли эквиваленты для методов normal и cper ?

Comment: Про `confidence intervals` было здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033511/compute-a-confidence-interval-from-sample-data

Comment: спасибо, посмотрим